# How to add audio to Java JFrame in BlueJ?

Tags: java, swing, audio, jframe, javasound

I am doing a brick breaker game for Computer Science class and I am trying to add background music to it. I am using a `JFrame` in BlueJ and the audio is a .WAV file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code pasted below is what I have already tried. I am calling `music();` in my second screen of the game.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import sun.audio.*;
import sun.audio.AudioData;


public static void music()
    {
        AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
        AudioStream BGM;
        AudioData MD;
        ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
        try
        {
            BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("gambino.wav"));
            MD = BGM.getData();
            loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(MD);
        }
        catch(IOException error)
        {
        }

        MGP.start(loop);
    }
```

It compiles but no audio plays.

Comment: First of all, don't silently ignore the `IOException`. Perhaps the .wav file cannot be found, or something else went wrong? Currently you wouldn't know about it. At the very minimum at least print the error stacktrace to rule out any of these issues.

Comment: 1) `import sun.audio.*;` No, no, a ***thousand times NO!*** Listen to the compiler warnings, investigate their meaning and fix the problem. Classes in the undocumented, subject to change without notice `sun` packages should not be used in our code. Instead use the public, documented and thereby guaranteed until deprecated classes in the `javax.sound.sampled` package. Or more specifically in this case, a [`Clip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html). 2) `catch(IOException error)
        {
        }` and when **that** is corrected, ..

Comment: .. Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 3) While that code imports the `javax.swing.JFrame`, it creates no instance of one, so even once the classes are fixed and the exceptions investigated and corrected, there will still be no sound given the `Thread` running the `main` will end right after `MGP.start(loop);`. Creating and showing a `JFrame` will prevent that, since it will be run on the non-daemon Event Dispatch Thread.